# htaccess rewrite causing infinite redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I need to rewrite a URL from something like

`/index.php?option=com_scoreboard&view=scoreboard&agent=001C0000016rJeUIAU`

to

`/quote/?agent=001C0000016rJeUIAU`.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} agent=(\w+)&?
RewriteRule ^index.php /quote/?agent=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Which works fine and dandy, but it ends in an infinite loop.  And I know why too, it's because it keeps finding `agent=`.  What should I be adding to my rewrite rules to stop this?

I've also tried variations like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=\w+?&agent=(\w+)&?
RewriteRule ^index.php /quote/?agent=%1 [R=301,L]
```

But it ends in the same infinite redirect.

This is for a Joomla site as well, if that helps.  So after this rule is the standard Joomla rewrites.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bette to `THE_REQUEST` variable instead and make sure to keep this rule as the **first rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?agent=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^ /quote/?agent=%1 [R=301,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Comment: ok css/js etc is a different problem due to use of relative links. To fix you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: Actually you original answer does work.  The issue I'm having with resources having the /quote/ in the front has nothing to do with the rewrite but something else all together.  Thanks!